# Angular2 - Adding new item to Select2 (ng2-select2)

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I'm using [ng2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) in my Angular2 project and I want to create new item if it's not in the list (only **one** item) and store it my component.ts to use it in my submitForm later. It seems that I need to use to `tokenizer` or `tokenSeparators` but how?

this is my html code:

```
<select2 [data]="generals" (valueChanged)="generalChanged($event)"></select2>
```

and this is the minimized version of my component.ts :

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  public options: Select2Options;
  public generals: Array<Select2OptionData>;
  productForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {

    this.generals = [
        { id: '1', text: 'Red' }, { id: '2', text: 'Blue' }
    ];
  }

  generalChanged(data: { value: string }) {
    const control = this.productForm.controls['general'];
    control.setValue(data.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

select2Options: any = {
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    tags: []
  };

add the tags: [] to select2Options